# Play station Plus account on 2 PS4

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

Hi I searched many sites about playstation plus / playstation 4 but instead of help I've found bunch of contradictory answers.

Thing is I've bought playstation 4 and playstation plus subscription. And now I wonder if its somehow possible to use my +account on other PS4 console? Because very often I'm at my girl's house. I found some info about plus benefits to other acc on the same console but this is not that interests me - in this case I would simply use my acc. Unfortunately I saw somewhere in that ps+ can be activated only on 1 PS4 console, but its good to ask someone who maybe is familiar in this matter. If its not possible, this would be very stupid - taking console every couple days? or buying another ps+ acc and all games :|

PS: Yea I'm complete console noob, all life with computers and now huge change.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to log in on her PS4 fine. What they are referring to is registering a PS4 to your account, which can only be registered or unregistered every six months I believe.

Comment: That's completely correct. Also keep in mind that digital games have DRM on PS4. If the PS4 you've logged in to ain't your main console (the PS4 tied to your account), you cant play the digital games unless you're connected on PSN on that PS4.